# How can I post the same data to two different handlers depending on the button clicked?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

*[See updates at bottom]*

I have a Razor page with a form on it. I want to have two buttons on that form, that perform a slightly different action - both using the same posted form data.

I tried using the `asp-page-handler` helper on the second button, but it doesn't seem to add anything to the HTML (I would expect it to add a `formaction` attribute to the `<button>` element, but it doesn't add anything at all).

Here's an example page:

```
@page  "{id?}"
@model IndexModel

@tagHelperPrefix x:
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<p>Current value is @Model.Foo</p>

<x:form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <button type="submit">Default</button>
    <button type="submit" x:asp-page-handler="Alternative">Alternative</button>
</x:form>
```

... and here's the corresponding page model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyWebApplication.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string Foo { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(int? id)
        {
        }

        public void OnPostAsync(string foo)
        {
            Foo = foo;
        }

        public void OnPostAlternativeAsync(string foo)
        {
            Foo = foo.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

This is rendered as:

[image]

...where the generated HTML for the form is:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <button type="submit">Default</button>
    <button type="submit" x:asp-page-handler="Alternative">Alternative</button>
</form>
```

The fact that the `x:asp-page-handler` attribute is still in the generated HTML makes me think that the Razor engine hasn't recognized it. I've tried taking off the `x:` prefix, but that didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

OK, I tried removing the tag prefix *and* removing the `@tagHelperPrefix` line, and that made a difference. A `formaction` is added to the second `<button>` element as expected.

However:

- that's really annoying - the `@tagHelperPrefix` is not something I want to lose, and
- now *both* buttons are triggering the "Alternative" action, even though only one of them has the `formaction`!

Here's the new generated HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <button type="submit">Default</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="/?handler=Alternative">Alternative</button>
</form>
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

OK, so If I put `asp-page-handler=""` on the "default" button, then each button goes to the correct handler, which is fine.

The last question that remains, then, is: **how can I make this work with the tag helper prefix**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Answering my own question in case this helps others.]*

It turns out that:

1. The tag-helper-prefix only applies to *elements*, not *attributes*, so it should be `asp-page-handler="..."` rather than `x:asp-page-handler="..."` even if the tag-helper-prefix is `x:`.
2. Those `asp-` attributes are only recognized within a tag that is tag-helper-enabled - which is *all* elements when no tag-helper-prefix is specified, or only elements with the tag-helper-prefix where one is specified. In my case, I had to change `<button ...>` to `<x:button ...>`.
3. If you specify `asp-page-handler` for one button, you need to specify it on *all* the buttons, even if you specify it as `""` to get the default action.